# Promql simple join queries

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm trying to join queries:

`node_filesystem_avail_bytes{instance="myhost"}` and `node_filesystem_size_bytes{instance="myhost"}`

I tried:

```
(node_filesystem_avail_bytes{instance="myhost"} ) + on(device,instance) group_left(size) (node_filesystem_size_bytes{instance="myhost"})
```

The trouble is that `size` label doesn't show up in the query result

These are the results of each query:

```
node_filesystem_avail_bytes{_tmp_assetalias="tmp", assetalias="Observability", assetid="1",device="/dev/mapper/vg_raid10-lv_storage_array", fstype="xfs", instance="myhost", job="datacenter-node", mountpoint="/storage_array", sg="prod-cluster1"}
3161558106112
node_filesystem_avail_bytes{_tmp_assetalias="tmp", assetalias="Observability", assetid="1", device="/dev/rbd0", fstype="xfs", instance="myhost",  job="datacenter-node", mountpoint="/var/lib/jenkins", sg="prod-cluster1"}
490332598272
node_filesystem_avail_bytes{_tmp_assetalias="tmp", assetalias="Observability", assetid="1", device="/dev/sda1", fstype="vfat", instance="myhost",  job="datacenter-node", mountpoint="/boot/efi", sg="prod-cluster1"}
```

```
node_filesystem_size_bytes{_tmp_assetalias="tmp", assetalias="Observability", assetid="1", device="/dev/mapper/vg_raid10-lv_storage_array", fstype="xfs", instance="myhost", job="datacenter-node", mountpoint="/storage_array", sg="prod-cluster1"}
3197869645824
node_filesystem_size_bytes{_tmp_assetalias="tmp", assetalias="Observability", assetid="1",  device="/dev/rbd0", fstype="xfs", instance="myhost", job="datacenter-node", mountpoint="/var/lib/jenkins", sg="prod-cluster1"}
5495421140992
node_filesystem_size_bytes{_tmp_assetalias="tmp", assetalias="Observability", assetid="1", device="/dev/sda1", fstype="vfat", instance="myhost", job="datacenter-node", mountpoint="/boot/efi", sg="prod-cluster1"}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your query? Simply show both values in something like grafana in table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `size` label in `node_filesystem_size_bytes` metric. If you want converting the metric value to `size` label, then this isn't supported by PromQL, mostly because the `size` label will have potentially unbound number of possible values, so this may result in [high cardinality issues](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/faq/#what-is-high-cardinality).